# Circular Arrangement 4 parameters

Tags: logical-deduction

P, Q, R, S, T, and U are six sports persons who are also recipients of Arjuna award for the year 2017. During the felicitation ceremony, the six persons were seated around a circular table. Three of them play a different team sport among - cricket, football, and hockey, and the other three play different individual sport from among - chess, fencing and high-jump. Also, three of them are males and the other three are females. Further, the following information is known about them:

The persons who play team sports sits neither adjacent nor opposite each other.
Any two persons who play games whose name start with the same letter are not opposite each other.
P, the gentleman who won the award for high-jump, is sitting to the right of S, who plays cricket.
Every male has females as his neighbors, and every female has males as her neighbors.
Q is seated opposite T, and is two places away from R, who plays individual sport.

Question is to map positions , persons , sports and gender.

Comment: Hello! If this question comes from another source, please be sure to specify it. Other than that, interesting puzzle :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

> Q/male/chess, S/female/cricket, P/male/high-jump, T/female/hockey, R/male/fencing, U/female/football

### Explanation

We are given the following background information:

- P, Q, R, S, T, and U are six sports persons who are also recipients of Arjuna award for the year 2017.
- During the felicitation ceremony, the six persons were seated around a circular table.
- Three of them play a different team sport among - cricket, football, and hockey, and the other three play different individual sport from among - chess, fencing and high-jump.
- Also, three of them are males and the other three are females.

Further, the following information is known about them:

1. The persons who play team sports sits neither adjacent nor opposite each other.
2. Any two persons who play games whose name start with the same letter are not opposite each other.
3. P, the gentleman who won the award for high-jump, is sitting to the right of S, who plays cricket.
4. Every male has females as his neighbors, and every female has males as her neighbors.
5. Q is seated opposite T, and is two places away from R, who plays individual sport.
6. From 3 and 4, we know that

   > S is female, since P is male and the two are adjacent.
7. From 1, we know that

   > team sport players are all 2 places apart, and therefore so are the individual sport players.
8. From 5 and 7, we know that

   > R and Q play individual sports, and T plays a team sport.
9. From 4 and 7, we know that

   > either all males play team sports or all males play individual sports (and vice versa with females).
10. From 3 and 9, since P does high-jump which is an individual sport,

    > we know that all males do individual sports and all females do team sports.
11. From 3, we know

    > the order is SPfmfm (and looping).
12. From 8 and 10, we know that

    > Q and R are male, and therefore T and U are female.
13. From 5, we know

    > the order is one of QfRTmf or QfmTRf.
14. From 11 and 13, we know

    > the order is QSPTRU.
15. From 1 and 14, we know

    > the order of the sports they play is iCHtit.
16. From 15 and 2, we know

    > the individual C sport must be the first i, and the team H sport must be the first t, so we have CCHHFF.

Therefore the order is

> Q/male/chess, S/female/cricket, P/male/high-jump, T/female/hockey, R/male/fencing, U/female/football.